# querying json at the back-end

Tags: json, angularjs, nosql

I'm building an app with Angularjs with its data stored on json files, so basically i just $http them and have them sorted into the templates.

It was perfectly fine when every .json was ~2kB, now it's over 20kB, so i'm thinking of separating the various parts of the json files into smaller chucks so that every chunk would be exactly what the client needs to receive in order to view a single page in the app (or state) and nothing more. But i want to keep the files as they are, if that's possible.

So, this my question then - is it possible to query json files at the back-end and send to the client only the queried part of it? And if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the only way that I can think of is to use a server side code for that.
For example if we use PHP on the server side it would be something like this:

```
$string = file_get_contents("file.json");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
// server side pagination
```

The do some classic server side pagination.